# How can I get gnome-terminal to take up its whole screen area in Awesome WM?

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal, awesome-wm

Gnome-terminal only takes up around 98% of its allotted screen area in Awesome WM, so that it's flush against the left window, flush against the top, but ~5px from the right and ~7px from the bottom. Is there a way I can get it to take up the whole area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this lines to awful.rules.rules table in your rc file

```
{ rule = { class = "Gnome-terminal" },
  properties = { size_hints_honor = false } },
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd tried that same thing but with a lowercase G, and it wasn't working.